# YUI Uploader hangs after choosing file

Tags: yui, yui-uploader

Below is my entire code from a User control that contains the YUI Uploader.  Is there something I'm missing.  Right now, when I step through the javascript code in Firebug, it hangs on the first line of the upload() function.  I have a breakpoint on the first line of the ashx that handles the file, but it is never called. So, it doesn't get that far.  I figure I'm just missing something stupid.  I've used this control many times before with no issues.  I'm using all the css files and graphics provided by the samples folder in the YUI download.

If I'm not missing anything, is there a more comprehensive way of debuging this issue then through stepping through the javascript with FireBug. I've tried turning the logging for YUI on and off, and never get any logs anywhere.  I'm not sure where to go now.

```
<style type="text/css">
   #divFile
   {
        background-color:White;
        border:2px inset Ivory;
        height:21px;
        margin-left:-2px;
        margin-right:9px;
        width:125px;
   }
</style>
<ajaxToolkit:RoundedCornersExtender runat="server" Corners="All" Radius="6" ID="rceContainer" TargetControlID="pnlMMAdmin" />
<asp:Panel ID="pnlMMAdmin" runat="server" 
 Width="100%" BackColor="Silver" ForeColor="#ffffff" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="16px">
<div style="padding: 5px; text-align:center; width: 100%;">

<table style="width: 100% ; border: none; text-align: left;">
    <tr>
    <td style="width: 460px; vertical-align: top;">
        <!-- information panel -->
        <ajaxToolkit:RoundedCornersExtender runat="server" Corners="All" Radius="6" ID="RoundedCornersExtender1" TargetControlID="pnlInfo" />
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlInfo" runat="server" 
         Width="100%" BackColor="Silver" ForeColor="#ffffff" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="16px">
        <div id="infoPanel" style="padding: 5px; text-align:left; width: 100%;">
        <table>
        <tr><td>Chart</td><td>
        <table><tr><td><div id="divFile" ></div></td><td><div id="uploaderContainer" style="width:60px; height:25px"></div></td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2"><div id="progressBar"></div></td></tr></table>
</td></tr>

    </table>

</div></asp:Panel>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    WYSIWYG.attach('<%= txtComment.ClientID %>', full);
    var uploader = new YAHOO.widget.Uploader("uploaderContainer", "assets/buttonSkin.jpg");
    uploader.addListener('contentReady', handleContentReady);
    uploader.addListener('fileSelect', onFileSelect)
    uploader.addListener('uploadStart', onUploadStart);
    uploader.addListener('uploadProgress', onUploadProgress);
    uploader.addListener('uploadCancel', onUploadCancel);
    uploader.addListener('uploadComplete', onUploadComplete);
    uploader.addListener('uploadCompleteData', onUploadResponse);
    uploader.addListener('uploadError', onUploadError);
    function handleContentReady() {
        // Allows the uploader to send log messages to trace, as well as to YAHOO.log
        uploader.setAllowLogging(false);

        // Restrict selection to a single file (that's what it is by default,
        // just demonstrating how).
        uploader.setAllowMultipleFiles(false);

        // New set of file filters.
        var ff = new Array({ description: "Images", extensions: "*.jpg;*.png;*.gif" });

        // Apply new set of file filters to the uploader.
        uploader.setFileFilters(ff);
    }
    var fileID;
    function onFileSelect(event) {
        for (var item in event.fileList) {
            if (YAHOO.lang.hasOwnProperty(event.fileList, item)) {
                YAHOO.log(event.fileList[item].id);
                fileID = event.fileList[item].id;
            }
        }
        uploader.disable();

        var filename = document.getElementById("divFile");
        filename.innerHTML = event.fileList[fileID].name;

        var progressbar = document.getElementById("progressBar");
        progressbar.innerHTML = "Please wait... Starting upload.... ";
        upload(fileID);
    }
    function upload(idFile) {
        // file hangs right here. **************************
        progressBar.innerHTML = "Upload starting... ";
        if (idFile != null) {

            uploader.upload(idFile, "AdminFileUploader.ashx", "POST");
            fileID = null;
        }
    }
    function handleClearFiles() {
        uploader.clearFileList();
        uploader.enable();
        fileID = null;

        var filename = document.getElementById("divFile");
        filename.innerHTML = "";

        var progressbar = document.getElementById("progressBar");
        progressbar.innerHTML = "";
    }
    function onUploadProgress(event) {
        prog = Math.round(300 * (event["bytesLoaded"] / event["bytesTotal"]));
        progbar = "<div style=\"background-color: #f00; height: 5px; width: " + prog + "px\"/>";

        var progressbar = document.getElementById("progressBar");
        progressbar.innerHTML = progbar;
    }
    function onUploadComplete(event) {
        uploader.clearFileList();
        uploader.enable();

        progbar = "<div style=\"background-color: #f00; height: 5px; width: 300px\"/>";
        var progressbar = document.getElementById("progressBar");
        progressbar.innerHTML = progbar;
        alert('File Uploaded');
    }

    function onUploadStart(event) {
        alert('upload start');
    }

    function onUploadError(event) {
        alert('upload error');
    }

    function onUploadCancel(event) {
        alert('upload cancel');
    }

    function onUploadResponse(event) {
        alert('upload response');
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there is a case mismatch in the name of the progressbar variable: you refer to it as progressbar everywhere else, but as progressBar in the upload() function.

An even bigger problem is that you define the progressbar variable inside the onFileSelect function. Because of that, the variable is limited in scope and should not be accessible anywhere else.

See if moving the definition for progressbar out of there (or freshly grabbing it from the DOM everywhere it's used by using getElementById) and fixing the case mismatch solves your issues.

Comment: holy smoke.. Ok.. that was exactly it.. good catch.. but, Why the hell did it not tell me that in the Error Console, or in the javascript console in Fire Bug.  Things like this irritate me when working with javascript... the inability to get good debug information.

Answer (score 1):

YUI 2.8 has issues with events and the uploader. It won't work unless you use 2.9 event and uploader. I wasted more time than I want to admit trying to get 2.8 to work. I hope this saves someone that time.